# App crashes when setting a NSObject inside another NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I have a NSObject called friend and another NSObject called currentUser.
There's a property inside currentUser of friend type (friendToSendMimo). But Whenever I try to set another friend object to it... the app crashes with the error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[currentUser setFriendToSendMimo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d29810'

My question is: How can I have a property that is from a NSObject?

Heres the currentUser header:

```
#import "friend.h"
@interface currentUser : NSObject<NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *token;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong)UIImage *userImg;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic,strong)friend *friendToSendMimo; //is there another way of setting this NSObject?
```

and the code crashes like here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //thisUser was set as currentUser
    thisUser.friendToSendMimo = [thisUser.friendsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but for other people to read your code you should begin your class names with UpperCase letters.

Comment: Depending on what version of Xcode you're using, you may need to have `@synthesize friendToSendMimo;` in your `@implementation` for `currentUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception reason is "Unrecognized selector". That usually means you're asking it to perform a method that it has no knowledge of. Have you tried allocating and initializing the friendToSendMimo property before accessing it?

Comment: After initializing and synthesizing the variable... it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. More importantly though, do you understand why you had to allocate and initialize it first before attempting to access it?